# Let $f$ be continuous such that $\int^x_0{f(t)dt} = \int^1_x{f(t)dt}$. Show that $f(t) = 0$ for all $ t \in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous such that

$\int^x_0{f(t)dt} = \int^1_x{f(t)dt}$ for all $ x \in [0,1]$. Show that $f(t) = 0$ for all $ t \in [0,1]$

I want to solve this using FTC. I tried expanding first: $\int^x_0{f(t)dt} = f(x) - f(0) = f(1) = f(x) = \int^1_x{f(t)dt}$
I think we then differentiate with respect to $t$, but that had led me nowhere

Comment: BTW, as a rule, $\int^x_0 \, f(t)\, dt \ne f(x) - f(0)$, contrary to your assertion.  To confirm this, try it with $f(t) = t$. You're not quoting the FTC correctly...

Comment: Because $f$ is continuous in a closed interval it have a primitive. For this case you can setup $\int_a^x f(t)\mathrm d t=F(x)-F(a)$. From here is easy to conclude that $f(t)=0$ in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

From your assumption, $$ 0=\int_0^x f(t)\, dt - \int_x^1 f(t)\, dt $$

Differentiating both sides gives $2f(x)=0$.

Comment: do you mean $2f(t) = 0$?

Comment: No. $t$ is the variable of integration and $x$ is the limit of integration, so $x$ it is.

Comment: It's $x$ because you differentiate with respect to $x$. so you have $f(x)=0$. However, it's just a dummy variable so that you can use any letter you want.

Comment: As long as it is the limit in the integrals.

Comment: right. So to continue from your comment, then we have shown that $f(x) =0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, and thus this shows that $f(t) = 0$ for all $t \in$ same interval?